# Google Workspace add-on in Apps Script External/Testing status -- how test users can add it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace-add-ons

I am puzzled about what is the right way to arrange testing collaboration of the Workspace add-on, as there seem to be two different places to share the test access (none of which works for me quite yet): the access sharing from the Apps Script UI, and the Test users listing under the attached GCP project.

Any hints would be appreciated! :)

The things that confuse to me:

1. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/testing-workspace-addons) seems to say I would need to give editor access to the script project to a tester. However, when I share the app script project edit access to somebody, then they can open the app script project, but when they click on the Deploy > Test deployments, they get the error message "Something went wrong. Please reload the page to try again."
2. What is the meaning of [adding "Test users" to the OAuth consent screen](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/configure-oauth-consent) of the attached GCP project? What is the effect of adding or not adding somebody there while I would have to share the script project from the Apps Script UI with editor access anyways (having user listed in the "Test users" list didn't solve the "Something went wrong" error message)? If those "Test users" should be able to add the not yet published add-on to their workspace, then how exactly? The bubble-tooltip when you hover over the ?-mark at "Extenal" type says: "Your app will only be available to users you add to the list of test users." Then how those test users can add that app? The app is not yet published -- it is not yet searchable from Marketplace -- where is the UI feature that would allow test users listed here to add the add-on that is in External/Testing state?

Comment: Are your test users part of a Google Workspace or general Google accounts like gmail.com?

Comment: @FernandoLara, part of a Google Workspace (from different org, though, not the same Workspace domain where the app is served from).

Comment: As far as I know the correct way to test this is using the first option you mentioned, however since other Google Workspace users are getting an error, I would strongly recommend contacting [Google Workspace support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en)

Comment: I'm having the same issue and also getting the same "Something went wrong. Please reload the page to try again." message. Using the developer tools to see the response to the https://script.google.com/_/AppsPlatformConsoleUi/data/batchexecute I was able to get this additional detail on the error: "Only users in the same domain as the script owner may deploy this script". I agree with @LostPadawan: What's the point in registering test users if they cannot install the add-on hence they cannot test it?.

Comment: I have also been experiencing this same issue. Have you found any workaround?  I have a unique situation where I want to share a gmail addon with a couple of different organizations but not have it public and go through all of that work.

Comment: Well, I got here having my fingers crossed hoping to see a solution...